# jQuery: Trying to display a box when hovering over an image

Tags: jquery

I have a JSFiddle up and running that displays what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/qnWpy/8/

The bug I'm running into here is that when ever the mouse is hovering over the .description class the box shows and then disappears. I suspect this happens because at the time I am hovering over the .description class and there is no jQuery code connected to it. How can I get rid of this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in replace of your current javascript

```
$(".dateSpot").hover(function() {
   $(".description",this).fadeToggle();
});
```

You want to change the selector to its parent. As long as your mouse is within that box, the hover persists.